# Split the String with special character

Tags: java, regex, spring

> Could you advise for this special character ? how we can replace and
>   split in java ?

Symbol in notepad :-[image]

Sample Code : Since its has special character.
[image]

Comment: Maybe split on 'the caracter preceding `/`'?

Comment: its work with special character, but i would like to replace with character and split it .

Comment: is this Control Character ?

Comment: try this`data.split("\\W+")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only bell characters, you can use:

```
String data="164/165/165"; //the hidden bells are there, generated via echo $'164\a/165\a/165' | pbcopy
System.out.println("length with hidden bells: "+data.length());

String elems [] = data.split("\\a/");
for(String e:elems) {
    System.out.println(e);
    System.out.println(e.length());
}
```

**output:**

```
length with hidden bells: 13
164
3
165
3
165
3
```

You can also use the hexadecimal notation: `\x07`

**See:** https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_4/cfg_fund/command/reference/cfnapph.html

**Notes:**

If you have different special characters you can create a char class via the hexadecimal values or you can simply use `\D+` if you are only interested in extracting digits from the string or `\\W+` if your string also contains letters. Also if your `/` is **always** preceded by a character you want to discard, then `./` should work fine too.